# How to send video stream to soap web service

Tags: android, video-streaming

I need to send recorded video stream to web service.

I'm doing encoding video stream using Base 64 but im getting **out of memory exception**. So I'm thinking another way to do this.

I searched for this but I can't find any reference link.

Is there another way to send the video that I can use?

Comment: SOAP is XML based, so you would to have to encode the video (e.g. with Base64) and send it to your web service. Am I wrong there?

Comment: @Knickedi you are right. im dng the same encoding using Base 64, bt im getting out of memory exception. so im thinking other way to do this... pls tell me if u hav any idea.... thanks

Comment: Compress before send? Base64 will do `newSize = videoSize / 3 * 4`. Maybe not using a web service? But you should metion that all in your question, not in the comment...

Comment: @Knickedi, i edited the question. im not doing any compress video. Im sending video stream as a encoded string to web service. Pls let me how to compress and send to webservice. thanks

Comment: I assume a raw video is a large file so I would seek for a method to compress / encode it before send (this should be your main problem). I never did that so unfortunately I can't give you more advices.

Answer (score 2):

Byte64 encoding alone expands data sizes to 4/3 their original size. On a video file this is an exceptional amount of overhead. Most likely you haven't seen any links on this topic due to the inability to use such a solution on any current infrastructure.

I'd highly recommend that you start looking into prepackaged transcoding solutions for your needs until you have a better understanding of this problem domain. Otherwise you are going to have a hard time finding people who want to take up your questions on stack overflow for fear of being downvoted when they have to explain to you that your entire premise is flawed and can be proven so mathematically.

For example let's assume that you are trying to push standard definition video (640x480) at 30 frames per second. Let's also say that the video is in the standard RGB format with 8 bits per color band, 24 bits per pixel. The math for this would be:

width x height x bytes per pixel x frame per second x Byte64 overhead = bytes per second

640 x 480 x 3 x 30 x 4/3 = 36,864,000

35MB per second

Remembering that most throughput measurements are in mega bits per second rather than mega bytes per second this translates to 281.25Mb/s. With those kind of bandwidth needs you are going to have a hard time finding a wireless connection that can meet your data needs and face quite a real threat of saturating a hardwired network connection. At the present time you need to compress your video files and you need to use something other than soap or use SOAP extensions like MTOM which allow data streaming.